# Windows Store project Xaml acting different than standard wpf project

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have ran into a odd issue. I setup the same project on a wpf project and a windows store project in visual studio 2012 and am getting different results from the same xaml code. My code is

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="120,120,120,120">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button></Button>
</Grid>
```

In my windows store project the button does not fill the grid, it just is a tiny button on the center left.

However in the wpf project the button fills the grid like I would expect. Why the difference? What do I need to set to have the button fill the contents of the grid like it has in the past?

EDIT: I have found if I set the vertical and horizontal alignment to stretch it fills the grid. But not sure why I have to explicitly state this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because while the default value of the VerticalAlignmentProperty is the same (Stretch) on both platforms - Jupiter specifies in the default style for the Button type that the VerticalAlignment should be set to Center. As to why that was chosen - it could be just an oversight, some engineer or designer's preference or it could be that it just works better with the standard project templates.